# Apache virtualhosts issue

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I trying to load 2 websites from the same ubuntu server - one via a domain name and the other via an IP address but I'm getting nowhere.

I am running a website on an EC2 instance. I pointed the default virtualhost at the website folder. The website has it's own domain name.

But then I needed to install phpmyadmin and I created a second virtualhost so that I now have the following in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1492 Oct 29 23:11 000-default.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6437 Jan  7  2014 default-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1500 Oct 29 22:34 phpmyadmin.conf
```

000-default.con has the following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com
    ServerName http://www.example.com
    ServerAlias http://example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example

    <Directory "/var/www/example">
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

While phpmyadmin.conf contains the following:

```
<VirtualHost phpmyadmin:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phpmyadmin/index.php

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is whenever I visit `example.com`, I get my website as expected.

But, I try loading phpmyadmin via the IP Address like: `x.x.x.x/phpmyadmin`, and I get a page not found error on mysite.com.

The same thing happens if I try `example.com/phpmyadmin`. I'm not sure how to fix this.

**UPDATE:**

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-106 /etc/apache2/sites-available $ apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server ip-10-0-0-106.eu-west-1.compute.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost ip-10-0-0-106.eu-west-1.compute.internal (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.conf:1)
                 alias http://example.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

Comment: attach the `apachectl -S` output.

Comment: @drookie: I have included the output you requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one valid, thus active virtual host. The other is invalid because the name `phpmyadmin` cannot be resolved to either of your IP addresses.

Instead you should use `<VirtualHost *>` in both hosts, and put the one that you want to handle the requests via IP address in the httpd.conf, so it would become the default one.

Comment: I have amended phpmyadmin.conf as you suggested but you've lost me on the second part of your instructions. What do you mean by httpd.conf?

Comment: I mean that when you addressing the web server via it's IP rather than name, the *default* vhost handles the request.

Comment: Thanks. IF I understood your instructions correctly, I editted the default virtualhost(httpd.conf) and it now loads phpmyadmin. The second vhosts files points to my directory folder and has the url set as servername but it lists the /var/www index of contents. Any suggestions to fix this, please?

Comment: Well, editing the default vhost isn't that good, I've advised you to *add* new virtualhost into yhe main config, to be sure it will be loaded first. Now you need to update the `apachectl -S` output. And to clarify are you running 2.2 or 2.4 branch.

Comment: I've updated the new output of apachectl -S

Comment: Okay, undo the changes you made to the default virtualhost in the httpd.conf and pyut this into the `000-default.conf`, that should do the trick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47714/discussion-between-sisko-and-drookie).